# How to change multidimensional php array into simple associative array with values as keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Language is **PHP**.

So I want to turn a multidimensional array into a simple associative array that uses every second value as a key and every third value as a value to that key.

The initial array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Adam
        [value] => 150
    ),

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Bob
        [value] => 120
    ),

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Charlie
        [value] => 175
    )

)
```

I want to turn it into a simple associative array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
Adam => 150,
Bob => 120,
Charlie => 175
)
```

I tried (and failed with) something like this:

```
$initialArray;
$arrayPrepped = array();
    foreach ($initialArray as $part) {
        foreach ($part as $name => $value) {
            if ($name == 'name') {
                $key = $value;
            } elseif ($name == 'value') {
                $finalvalue = $value;
            }
            $finalpart = array($key => $finalvalue);
        }
        array_merge($initialArray, $finalpart);
    }
```

Comment: `$arrayPrepped = array_column($initialArray, 'value', 'name');`

Comment: Just keep in mind when you do this that if there are any entries that happen to have the same `name`, the `value` of that key will be overwritten and you'll only get the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this one-liner!

```
print_r(array_column($initialArray, 'value', 'name'));
```

Read up on [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Answer (score 2):

Your original value looks like:

```
$a = Array
(
    Array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Adam',
        'value' => 150
    ),
    Array
    (
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Job',
        'value' => 200
    ),

);
```

**Then work on:**

```
$myarr = [];
foreach ($a as $item) {
    $myarr[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [Adam] => 150
    [Job] => 200
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through array and setup value into new array in that way.

```
$initialArray = [
    0 => [
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'Adam',
        'value' => 150,
    ],

    1 => [
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'Bob',
        'value' => 120,
    ],

    2 => [
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'Charlie',
        'value' => 175,
    ],
];
$arrayPrepped = array();
foreach ($initialArray as $part) {
    $arrayPrepped[$part['name']] = $part['value'];
}
```

[Here is](https://3v4l.org/QVob5) example of execution